# Gimp Projects default Unix location

Tags: gimp

I am trying to do a series of tutorials to guide others on how to share a full development system to Unix running in VirtualBox. Oddly, the last piece of my tutorial (The Gimp) seems to be the only software that lacks a default Projects directory. Am I missing something?

I use Gimp on Windows and Ubuntu, but have never taken much notice until now of this. It seems pretty common for a software of this type to have a default directory to store projects to. Doing so, would allow directories to be shared between host and guest systems like in VirtualBox, but more importantly assist those that like to write scripts not just for themselves, but others too. eg. I can refer to `~/IdeaProjects` in a script in confidence that the directory contains Jetbrains IDEA projects.

*This is a Gimp issue as it is both on Windows and Unix Gimp that have no projects directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it indeed does not have, and will just save to the system sugested (~/Documents, generally) just like OpenOffice, text editors, and a lot of other programs.

There are directories for the resources GIMP uses, like plug-ins, textures, brushes and so, which can be set in the prefrences dialog (and are stored in a ~/.gimprc file which can be parsed. But no default folder for user images.